# How to update compose function with newer data?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to recompose a compose function after getting new data?
I am displaying an initial image from drawable at start but the user can add image from his gallery.
How can I display this image instead of the initial one using the same compose function.
Remember doesn't work as I get the new image data outside the compose function

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question right, but why can't you just pass the image (or whatever your composable uses to render that image, e.g. a path) as an argument to your composable function?

then use `remember` in the parent to keep the state

Comment: The path is get updated outside the compose function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty simple thing with the state in Compose:

```kotlin
var pickedImage by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
Image(
    painter = pickedImage?.let {
        // this is from coil.compose
        rememberImagePainter(it)
    } ?: painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
    "...",
)
Button(onClick = {
    // pick image
    pickedImage = "new/image/url"
}) { 
    Text("Pick image")
}
```

I suggest you start with [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.